# Checking Wi-Fi enabled or not on Android

Tags: android, wifi, status

What would the code be for checking whether the Wi-Fi is enabled or not?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to see if wifi is connected in android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3841317/how-to-see-if-wifi-is-connected-in-android)

Comment: Upvote to compensate for sour grapes :)

Answer (score 119, accepted):

```
WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
if (wifiManager.isWifiEnabled()) {
  // wifi is enabled
}
```

For details check [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html)

Comment: if (wifi.isWifiEnabled())
  {//wifi is enabled
  }

Comment: this needs <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />.  Sorry if this is obvious but I got an unexpected runtime error.

Comment: Please edit answer to include the needed permissions. My IDE is also suggesting that I use `getApplciationContext()` rather than `getSystemService()`

Answer (score 25):

The above answers work fine. But don't forget to add the right permissions in the Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE"/>
```

Hope it helps ..

Comment: I don't think we need CHANGE_WIFI_STATE

Comment: @LoveForDroid : why ?

Answer (score 17):

The top answer is correct, but not up to date because this code may leak memory on certain devices.

Therefore the better answer would be:

```
WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
if (wifiManager.isWifiEnabled()) {
  // wifi is enabled
}
```

Permissions in app=>mainfests=>AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
```

Reference: https://www.mysysadmintips.com/other/programming/759-the-wifi-service-must-be-looked-up-on-the-application-context

Comment: You are right, but on your second uses-permission line, change the "(" to "/".

Comment: @CuriousMind Thank you, I changed it.

Answer (score 8):

```
public static boolean wifiState() {
    WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
    return wifiManager.isWifiEnabled();
}
```