# How To Check if WiFi Enabled On Phone

Tags: java, android, wifi, isenabled

I'm trying to develop an android app with java and xml, and I would like some guidance on how to determine if wifi is enabled on the phone that the app is on or not. Any help would be appreciated. I've tried using these methods, but they all don't detect if my wifi port is open or closed correctly. I'm afraid these methods are out of date. Does anyone have an up to date method?

```
//determine if wifi is enabled
    //1st try
    wifi =Settings.Secure.getInt(cr, Settings.Secure.WIFI_ON);

    //second try
    wifi=Settings.Global.getInt(cr, Settings.Global.WIFI_ON, 0);

    //3rd try
    WifiManager wifi = (WifiManager)getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
    if (wifi.isWifiEnabled()){
        //wifi is enabled
        wifiInt=1;
    }
    else
        wifiInt=0;
```

Comment: Here you go

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3841317/how-to-see-if-wifi-is-connected-in-android

Comment: possible duplicate of [Checking Wifi enabled or not in Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6593858/checking-wifi-enabled-or-not-in-android)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Checking the state of WiFi can be done by obtaining an instance to the WiFi system service as below:

```
WifiManager wifi = (WifiManager)getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
```

from this, the method `isWifiEnabled()` can be used to determine if WiFi is enabled. As below:

```
WifiManager wifi = (WifiManager)getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
if (wifi.isWifiEnabled()){
    //TODO: Code to execute if wifi is enabled.
}
```

Comment: To avoid memory leaks use `getApplicationContext().getSystemService(WIFI_SERVICE);`

Answer (score 1):

Both WiFi and Mobile data u can check this way..

```
ConnectivityManager connManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

NetworkInfo mWifi = connManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
NetworkInfo mData = connManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);

if(mWifi.isConnected()||mData.isConnected()){
    //Do something when data is available
}
```

To check for any active network connection:

```
private boolean isNetworkAvailable() {

        //Call this method to check network connection.

        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        return activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnected();

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try to get wifi connected wifi name

```
WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager)HomeScreen.this.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
            if(wifiManager != null) 
            {
                if(wifiManager.isWifiEnabled())
                {
                    WifiInfo connectedWifiInfo = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
                    if(connectedWifiInfo != null)
                    {
                        if(connectedWifiInfo.getBSSID() != null)
                        {   
                            // connected
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            // not connected
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // not connected
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    // not connected
                }
            }
```