# How to get Wi-FI state (ON/OFF) on sdk 28

Tags: android, kotlin

There are a lot of answers about how to check if the device is connected on wifi or Data, using:

```
hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI/TRANSPORT_CELLULAR)
```

What is the current non-deprecated way to see if Wifi is enabled (not connected), like:

```
BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter().isEnabled
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I see if Wi-Fi is connected on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3841317/how-do-i-see-if-wi-fi-is-connected-on-android)

Comment: TYPE_WIFI is deprecated

Comment: Found this solution:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6593858/checking-wi-fi-enabled-or-not-on-android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
WifiManager.isWifiEnabled()
```

returns true if Wifi is enabled. [link to doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html#isWifiEnabled())

---

Another a good option is:

```
WifiManager.getWifiState()
```

returns an int: One of `WIFI_STATE_DISABLED, WIFI_STATE_DISABLING, WIFI_STATE_ENABLED, WIFI_STATE_ENABLING, WIFI_STATE_UNKNOWN`

[link to doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html#getWifiState())

Answer (score 0):

The first answer does exactly what i need without deprecation warning:
[Checking Wi-Fi enabled or not on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6593858/checking-wi-fi-enabled-or-not-on-android)

Comment: A link only answer is not an answer. Best to include the link as comment or mark this question as duplicate