# check if wireless is on (even if not connected to any network)

Tags: android, position, wireless

Can I check if the wireless is enabled, even if not connected to any network. I need wireless enabled to get more accurate gps readings. But I don't need to be concede to any of the networks (It  seams that unless wi-fi is active, the device can not use networks for positioning). For data transfer I will use the mobile network.

So, How do I check if wireless is activated?

Comment: How about this answer? [how to see if wifi is connected in android](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3841407/1513735)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
public boolean isWifiOn() {
     WifiManager wifi = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
     return wifi.isWifiEnabled();
}
```