# How do i create a app that check if there is wifi connection around? in android-eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse, video, wifi, android-wifi

How do i create a app that check if there is wifi connection around? using android eclipse?
if there is videos would be better because im a beginner and so it gets difficult and confused for me when i read the codes and don't know where to put them.
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [WifiManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html) class provides the API for interfacing with the Wi-Fi of the device. The [getConnectionInfo()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html#getConnectionInfo%28%29) method will return a [WifiInfo](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiInfo.html) object that will give you info about the current Wi-Fi connection. Also, here's one [tutorial](http://marakana.com/forums/android/examples/40.html) I found that may be helpful.

Comment: well i had a look and the app in the tutorial it only shows you how to scan and see the wifi network status, what i actually want is to see if there is wifi connection avaible and (i didn't mentioned it in the question, i forgot) to connect to the wifi network.

Comment: So is [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3841317/how-to-see-if-wifi-is-connected-in-android) more what you're looking for?

Comment: kinda, well i kept on looking up in the web and found some other stuff all relevant to these and got it working and yes, it shows my connection status, but i want to see network avaible and be able to connect to it, and we here had a look on the codes and tested it and its not what i was looking for :/ it only shows the status of it.