# Android:How can I check if wifi authenticated or not

Tags: android, android-wifi

My application is using wifi manager in android, but I am facing an error in a situation the situation is::WIFI is turned on but it is not authenticated(with our company wifi user name and password)at that time my application is force closing,

code I am using is

```
try{
    if (connectivityManager != null && 
       (connectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(1).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED) ||
       (connectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(0).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED))
    { 
        //You are connected, do something online.
        return true;
    }
    else if (connectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(0).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.DISCONNECTED ||  
             connectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(1).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.DISCONNECTED ) 
    {             
        //Not connected.        
        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You must be connected to the internet", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        loginTask.myPublishProgress("You must be connected to the internet");
        return false; 
    }   
    }
catch(NullPointerException ae)
   {
        ae.printStackTrace();
        loginTask.myPublishProgress("You must be connected to the internet");

   }
```

Comment: can you post your logcat?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi check the below answers:

[How to detect when WIFI Connection has been established in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5888502/android-wifi-how-to-detect-when-wifi-connection-has-been-established)

[How do I see if Wi-Fi is connected on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3841317/how-to-see-if-wifi-is-connected-in-android)

Comment: These answers only check effective connection, and don't provide enough detail to assert authentication is the issue. My comment elsewhere in this post: "don't know about old APIs, but SupplicantState will rarely provide enough transitions when a bad password is input to ensure authentication is the "disableReason" in the now hidden APIs - i.e. we can never know if authentication failed in recent APIs"

Comment: Agreed! For api Above 21 its possible to check using ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback() However, there is no solution check for api below 21, if anyone finds that solution please help. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Use [SupplicantState](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/SupplicantState.html)

```
SupplicantState supState; 
wifiManager = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
WifiInfo wifiInfo = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
supState = wifiInfo.getSupplicantState();
```

See [this answer in  stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3841444/1051147)

If   `COMPLETED - All authentication completed.`

Comment: don't know about old APIs, but SupplicantState will rarely provide enough transitions when a bad password is input to ensure authentication is the "disableReason" in the now hidden APIs - i.e. we can never know if authentication failed in recent APIs

Comment: Not useful for me, my device wi-fi is not authenticated but this code returns me COMPLETED every time.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use

```
conectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(0) and getNetworkInfo(1).
```

Instead of that use

For WiFi

```
NetworkInfo conectivityManager = connectivity.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
```

For mobile networks(3g)

```
NetworkInfo conectivityManager = connectivity.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);
```

Cause on Jelly Beans will make trouble hardcoding values like that.