# Sending SMS with SQLite

Tags: java, android, sqlite, gps, sms

Please help me.. I have a problem in sending multiple SMS in which it will send to the contact numbers that are registered in my application. The contact numbers are stored in SQLite. The body of that SMS contains the current latitude and longitude of the user.
There is no problem in sending when I have internet, but when I don't have an internet, the SMS won't send.

```
    gps = new GPSTracker(NotAutoSOSAlert.this);
    if(gps.canGetLocation()) {
            longi=gps.getLongitude();
            lati=gps.getLatitude();
        }
        else {
            gps.showSettingsAlert();
        }
        getLocation();

if(longi != 0 && lati != 0) {
                    SharedPreferences shared = getSharedPreferences("Profile", MODE_PRIVATE);
                    String name = (shared.getString("profileName", "Not Found"));

                    List<ContactsConstructor> contacts = db.getAllContacts();   

                    for (ContactsConstructor cn : contacts) {
                        getLocation();
                        if(name == "") {
                            getProfNameDialog();
                        }

                        Log.d("id", String.valueOf(cn.getID()));
                        Log.d("name", name);
                        Log.d("conName", String.valueOf(cn.getName()));
                        Log.d("num", String.valueOf(cn.getPhoneNumber()));

                            Log.d("both", "not null");
                            String sms2 = cn.getID() + " " + name + " " + cn.getName() + " Help me!!.. My life is in danger!!.. "
                                    + "Here is my location latitude " + lati + " longitude " + longi 
                                    + " https://maps.google.com/?q=" + lati + "," + longi;
                            String sms1 = "1 " + name + " venom Help me!!.. My life is in danger!!.. "
                                    + "Here is my location latitude " + lati + " longitude " + longi 
                                    + " https://maps.google.com/?q=" + lati + "," + longi;
                            String cp = cn.getPhoneNumber();

                            PendingIntent piSent=PendingIntent.getBroadcast(NotAutoSOSAlert.this, 0, new Intent("SMS_SENT"), 0);
                            PendingIntent piDelivered=PendingIntent.getBroadcast(NotAutoSOSAlert.this, 0, new Intent("SMS_DELIVERED"), 0);
                            SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
                            sms.sendTextMessage(cp, null, sms2, piSent, piDelivered); } }
```

the getLocation function

```
    private void getLocation() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    listUpdaterExecuter = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(5);
    listUpdaterExecuter.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
        private Runnable update = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {          
              // ln.setText(""+lng);
              // lt.setText(""+lat);
                gps = new GPSTracker(NotAutoSOSAlert.this);
                if(gps.canGetLocation()) {
                longi=gps.getLongitude();
                lati=gps.getLatitude();
                }
            }
        };

 @Override
        public void run() {
            runOnUiThread(update);
        }
    }, 5, 20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}
```

The onResume

```
    @Override
protected void onResume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onResume();

    smsSentReceiver=new BroadcastReceiver() {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            switch (getResultCode()) {
            case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS has been sent", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_GENERIC_FAILURE:
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Generic Failure", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NO_SERVICE:
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No Service", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NULL_PDU:
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Null PDU", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_RADIO_OFF:
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Radio Off", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            default:
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Generic Failure", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            }

        }
    };
    smsDeliveredReceiver=new BroadcastReceiver() {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            switch(getResultCode()) {
            case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS Delivered", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS not delivered", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            }
        }
    };
    registerReceiver(smsSentReceiver, new IntentFilter("SMS_SENT"));
    registerReceiver(smsDeliveredReceiver, new IntentFilter("SMS_DELIVERED"));
}
```

The onPause

```
    @Override
protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();
     unregisterReceiver(smsSentReceiver);
     unregisterReceiver(smsDeliveredReceiver);
}
```

The GPSTracker class

```
    public class GPSTracker extends Service implements LocationListener {

private final Context mContext;

// flag for GPS status
boolean isGPSEnabled = false;

// flag for network status
boolean isNetworkEnabled = false;

// flag for GPS status
boolean canGetLocation = false;

Location location; // location
double latitude; // latitude
double longitude; // longitude

// The minimum distance to change Updates in meters
private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 10; // 10 meters

// The minimum time between updates in milliseconds
private static final long MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES = 1000 * 60 * 1; // 1 minute

// Declaring a Location Manager
protected LocationManager locationManager;

public GPSTracker(Context context) {
    this.mContext = context;
    getLocation();
}

public Location getLocation() {
    try {
        locationManager = (LocationManager) mContext
                .getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

        // getting GPS status
        isGPSEnabled = locationManager
                .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

        // getting network status
        isNetworkEnabled = locationManager
                .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

        if (!isGPSEnabled && !isNetworkEnabled) {
            // no network provider is enabled
        } else {
            this.canGetLocation = true;

            // if GPS Enabled get lat/long using GPS Services
            if (isGPSEnabled) {
                if (location == null) {
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                            LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                            MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                            MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                    Log.d("GPS Enabled", "GPS Enabled");
                    if (locationManager != null) {
                        location = locationManager
                                .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                        if (location != null) {
                            latitude = location.getLatitude();
                            longitude = location.getLongitude();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            if (isNetworkEnabled) {
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                        LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                        MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                        MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                Log.d("Network", "Network");
                if (locationManager != null) {
                    location = locationManager
                            .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                    if (location != null) {
                        latitude = location.getLatitude();
                        longitude = location.getLongitude();
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return location;
}

/**
 * Stop using GPS listener
 * Calling this function will stop using GPS in your app
 * */
public void stopUsingGPS(){
    if(locationManager != null){
        locationManager.removeUpdates(GPSTracker.this);
    }      
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onDestroy();
    if(locationManager != null){
        locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
    }
}

/**
 * Function to get latitude
 * */
public double getLatitude(){
    if(location != null){
        latitude = location.getLatitude();
    }

    // return latitude
    return latitude;
}

/**
 * Function to get longitude
 * */
public double getLongitude(){
    if(location != null){
        longitude = location.getLongitude();
    }

    // return longitude
    return longitude;
}

/**
 * Function to check GPS/wifi enabled
 * @return boolean
 * */
public boolean canGetLocation() {
    return this.canGetLocation;
}

/**
 * Function to show settings alert dialog
 * On pressing Settings button will lauch Settings Options
 * */
public void showSettingsAlert(){
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);

    // Setting Dialog Title
    alertDialog.setTitle("GPS is settings");

    // Setting Dialog Message
    alertDialog.setMessage("GPS  or Wireless Networks is not enabled. Do you want to go to settings menu?");

    // On pressing Settings button
    alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Settings", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
            mContext.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    // on pressing cancel button
    alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        dialog.cancel();
        }
    });

    // Showing Alert Message
    alertDialog.show();
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    return null;
}
```

}

The ContactsConstructor class

```
    public class ContactsConstructor {
//private variables
    int _id;
    String _name;
    String _phone_number;

    // Empty constructor
    public ContactsConstructor(){

    }
    // constructor
    public ContactsConstructor(int id, String name, String _phone_number){
        this._id = id;
        this._name = name;
        this._phone_number = _phone_number;
    }

    // constructor
    public ContactsConstructor(String name, String _phone_number){
        this._name = name;
        this._phone_number = _phone_number;
    }
    // getting ID
    public int getID(){
        return this._id;
    }

    // setting id
    public void setID(int id){
        this._id = id;
    }

    // getting name
    public String getName(){
        return this._name;
    }

    // setting name
    public void setName(String name){
        this._name = name;
    }

    // getting phone number
    public String getPhoneNumber(){
        return this._phone_number;
    }

    // setting phone number
    public void setPhoneNumber(String phone_number){
        this._phone_number = phone_number;
    }
```

}

and the ContactsDbHelper Class

```
    public class ContactsDbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

static String DATABASE_NAME="alerto";
public static final String TABLE_NAME="contacts";
public static final String KEY_FNAME="fname";
public static final String KEY_NUMBER="number";
public static final String KEY_ID="id";

public ContactsDbHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String CREATE_TABLE="CREATE TABLE "+TABLE_NAME+" ("+KEY_ID+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, "+KEY_FNAME+" TEXT, "+KEY_NUMBER+" TEXT)";
    db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+TABLE_NAME);
    onCreate(db);
}

// Getting All Contacts
    public List<ContactsConstructor> getAllContacts() {
        List<ContactsConstructor> contactList = new ArrayList<ContactsConstructor>();
        // Select All Query
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_NAME;

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        // looping through all rows and adding to list
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                ContactsConstructor contact = new ContactsConstructor();
                contact.setID(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
                contact.setName(cursor.getString(1));
                contact.setPhoneNumber(cursor.getString(2));
                // Adding contact to list
                contactList.add(contact);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }

        // return contact list
        return contactList;
    }
```

}

The Logcat when I'm using the internet (No problem with this)

> 01-26 12:30:10.969: D/id(17370): 1
>
> 01-26 12:30:10.969: D/name(17370): Jingo
>
> 01-26 12:30:10.969: D/conName(17370): venom
>
> 01-26 12:30:10.969: D/num(17370): 09208689479
>
> 01-26 12:30:10.989: D/id(17370): 2
>
> 01-26 12:30:10.989: D/name(17370): Jingo
>
> 01-26 12:30:10.989: D/num(17370): 67993
>
> 01-26 12:30:11.009: D/id(17370): 3
>
> 01-26 12:30:11.009: D/name(17370): Jingo
>
> 01-26 12:30:11.009: D/conName(17370): jbmdd
>
> 01-26 12:30:11.009: D/num(17370): 4489

The Logcat when not using Internet.

> 01-26 12:35:08.999: D/id(17665): 1
>
> 01-26 12:35:08.999: D/name(17665): Jingo
>
> 01-26 12:35:08.999: D/conName(17665): venom
>
> 01-26 12:35:08.999: D/num(17665): 09208689479

It only logs the 1st contact registered in my application. Please help me Guys.. Thank you in advance!

I already solved it guys. The user just needs to check the Use Wireless Networks under the Location & Security Menu of Android Phone regardless if the user is connected to the WiFi

The problem now is, how can I check if the user checks the Wireless Networks under the Location & Security Menu of Android Phone? Please Help me with these

Comment: so what you want to do is check if wireless networks is available ?

Comment: Have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3841317/how-to-see-if-wifi-is-connected-in-android