# How do I check if the user is connected to a wifi network or not?

Tags: android, android-wifi

I know how to check if wifi is enabled or not.

Code:

```
WifiManager wifi = (WifiManager)getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
if(wifi.isWifiEnabled())
{
    //Code execution comes here
}
```

But how to find out if the user is actually *connected* to a nearby wifi network (or any wifi network for that matter)?

**EDIT:** I mean to ask, say if a user has logged in to a wifi network after typing in a password, then only would he be able to use that wifi. So is there anyway to check if has connected (logged in) to any wifi network?

Comment: please check for a signal strength correspondingly with respect to each  enabled wifi

Comment: I mean to say there will be a need to type a password to actually connect to some wifi networks. Is there a way to check if the user is already *logged in* to a wifi network or not?

Comment: check my ans for this :) may this will help u

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to see if wifi is connected in android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3841317/how-to-see-if-wifi-is-connected-in-android)

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use the ConnectivityManager  to get the state of the Wifi adapter.  By this you can [check](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/NetworkInfo.html)  if it is connected...

Method to check whether wifi is conected or not :-

```
public static Boolean checkWIFI(Activity activity) {
    Log.d("checkWIFI", "checkWIFI");

    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) activity
            .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();

    Log.d("NetworkInfo", "NetworkInfo" + netInfo);

    if (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting()) {
        return true;
    } else if (netInfo != null
            && (netInfo.getState() == NetworkInfo.State.DISCONNECTED
                    || netInfo.getState() == NetworkInfo.State.DISCONNECTING
                    || netInfo.getState() == NetworkInfo.State.SUSPENDED || netInfo
                    .getState() == NetworkInfo.State.UNKNOWN)) {
        return false;

    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

You need to add permission in your manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Good Luck!!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
ConnectivityManager connManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
NetworkInfo mWifi = connManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);

if (mWifi.isConnected()) {
    // Do whatever
}
```

Hope this helps.. :)

Comment: This will go into the if condition if the user is connectd to the wifi.. can I check if he has logged into the wifi network?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
ConnectivityManager con=(ConnectivityManager)getSystemService(Activity.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
boolean wifi=con.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI).isConnectedOrConnecting();

    //check Internet connection
    if(wifi)
    {
        //do what you want
    }else{
    }
```

also add require permissions

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Hope this will do the trick

Answer (score 0):

```
    /**
     * 
     * Method to check internet connection is available
     */

    public static boolean isInternetAvailable(Context context) {
        boolean haveConnectedWifi = false;
        boolean haveConnectedMobile = false;
        boolean connectionavailable = false;

        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo[] netInfo = cm.getAllNetworkInfo();

        NetworkInfo informationabtnet = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        for (NetworkInfo ni : netInfo) {
            try {

                if (ni.getTypeName().equalsIgnoreCase("WIFI"))
                    if (ni.isConnected())
                        haveConnectedWifi = true;
                if (ni.getTypeName().equalsIgnoreCase("MOBILE"))
                    if (ni.isConnected())
                        haveConnectedMobile = true;
                if (informationabtnet.isAvailable()
                        && informationabtnet.isConnected())
                    connectionavailable = true;

            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
                System.out.println("Inside utils catch clause , exception is"
                        + e.toString());
                e.printStackTrace();

            }
        }
        return haveConnectedWifi || haveConnectedMobile;
    }
```

I have tried the similar code in my project and is running.Hope this would help you...:)

Answer (score 0):

Just call this method for wifi network may this will help u :)

call like this `checkWiFi(this);`  // pass `context` with this method here i pass `this` for current activity

```
  public static final boolean checkWiFi(Context cn)
    {
        ConnectivityManager connManager = (ConnectivityManager) cn.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo mWifi = connManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);

        if (mWifi.isConnected())
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
```

also take permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```