# Programmatically restrict access of Mobile data for all apps in Android

Tags: android, application-settings

Can any one have any idea to do restrict mobile data access for a particular app in android.
Recently i found this feature on my MOTO G (2nd Gen) with 4.4.4 Kitkat version.

How to do it programmatically ?

This is the screenshot

[image]

Comment: For your own app you can do this: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/managing.html

Comment: [Please check this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24535172/2591002)

Comment: @MorrisonChang its quiet helpful (Y). I'm going through it.

Comment: @SweetWisherツ Its more about setting Mobile data limits and warning limit.

Comment: Do you want for your own app only ??

Comment: Yes i want it for my own app.

Comment: Rescale the image to 0.5 please, will you?

Comment: mean you want that your app don't use mobile data?? @ch3tan

Comment: Yea i don't want to access mobile data but Wifi. @sweetwisher

Comment: Then [this is what you need](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24432444/2591002)

Comment: Thanks @SweetWisherツ but i've to dig more on this. Thanks for quick response (Y)

Comment: @SweetWisherツ i did it for my personal app, but now i wanna know how to restrict Background data for other apps too.