# detect wifi status automatically in Android

Tags: android, android-wifi

In my app i have to known wifi status automatically that user is connected to Wifi or not without user action. Also I want to detect when user doesn't use app. Is there any way? I'm new to Android.

Comment: Good day

This post might help :

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3841317/how-to-see-if-wifi-is-connected-in-android

Comment: check android documents http://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/connectivity-monitoring.html#MonitorChanges

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best that worked for me:

AndroidManifest

```
<receiver android:name="com.AEDesign.communication.WifiReceiver" >
   <intent-filter android:priority="100">
      <action android:name="android.net.wifi.STATE_CHANGE" />
   </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

BroadcastReceiver class

```
public class WifiReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

   @Override
   public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

      NetworkInfo info = intent.getParcelableExtra(WifiManager.EXTRA_NETWORK_INFO);
      if(info != null) {
         if(info.isConnected()) {
            // Do your work. 

            // e.g. To check the Network Name or other info:
            WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager)context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
            WifiInfo wifiInfo = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
            String ssid = wifiInfo.getSSID();
         }
      }
   }
}
```

On recive will gets called automatically.

Answer (score 0):

```
WifiManager wifi = (WifiManager)getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
if (wifi.isWifiEnabled()){
//wifi is enabled
}
```

For details check [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html)

or

```
ConnectivityManager connManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
NetworkInfo networkInfo = connManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);

if (networkInfo.isConnected()) {
    // Do whatever
}
```