# NetworkInfo state for WIFI returns disconnected when no internet connection available android 5.0

Tags: android, android-wifi

I want to detect that Is Wifi connected to a network? Doesn't matter whether it has Internet connection or not. But my following code returns Disconnected when my Wifi is connected to a network(no internet) and 3G data is enabled.

```
public static boolean isWifiConnected(ConnectivityManager mConnectivity){
        android.net.NetworkInfo info = mConnectivity.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
        if (info == null ) {
            Log.e("network type","null");
            return false;
        }
        return info.isConnected();
    }
```

## Specification:

```
Android OS: 5.0.2
Moto g 1st generation
```

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3841317/how-to-see-if-wifi-is-connected-in-android

Answer (score 0):

> I want to detect that Is Wifi connected to a network? Doesn't matter
>   whether it has Internet connection or not.

If you doesn´t have any internet connection is impossible to determinate of what kind of connection you are disconnected!

More info:

> **[isConnected ()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/NetworkInfo.html#isConnected())**
>
> Indicates whether network connectivity exists and it is possible to
>   establish connections and pass data.
>
> Always call this before attempting to perform data transactions.
>
> **Returns true if network connectivity exists, false otherwise.**

Comment: In android 5.0 I noticed that if my wifi does't have internet connection(but connected to a network) then android automatically start 3G data connect(both wifi and 3G are connected simultaneously).

Comment: @Elenasys I choose only TYPE_WIFI NetworkInfo (1st line). So basically I'm checking is my WIFI is connected or not.

Comment: isConnected () : Returns true if network connectivity exists, false otherwise.

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to indicate the same thing. My wifi is connected with my router but my router doesn't have internet connection. In this scenario returns false(state == DISCONNECTED). It's happening only in Android >= 5.0

Comment: @shantanu The behavior of this method must have changed with Android 5.0.  I know that on 4.x, it will return true if the device is associated to a WiFi access point even if there is no connectivity, which is what it sounds like you are seeing as well.

Comment: @DanielNugent Is there any way that I can determine if Wifi is connected or not in Android 5.0 when 3G data is enable?