# Know if user is connected to determined wifi for some amount of time

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, mobile

Is it possible to know if a user is connected to a wifi connection that I know of (for example, I want the user to be connected to a wifi called 'MyWifi'), and if he is after some time execute a function with JavaScript/Jquery? If not, is it possible to do so in mobile's native language?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot check this with javascript/jQuery. All you can do is check if you're connected to a certain IP address, if you really want (using an asynchronous http request for example) but you cannot check the SSID of the Wifi network.

You can do this with the android SDK. Please refer to:
[How do I see if Wi-Fi is connected on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3841317/how-to-see-if-wifi-is-connected-in-android)