# Can we make an android app which works only when we connect to a specific Wi-fi Network?

Tags: java, android, networking, wifi

I want to know whether we can make an android app which works only when we connect to a specific wi-fi Network?
All help is much appreciated! I'm all out of ideas here. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
boolean onRightNetwork() {
    WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) App.getContext()
                        .getSystemService(App.getContext().WIFI_SERVICE);
                WifiInfo wifiInfo = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();

    return wifiInfo.getSSID().equals(NETWORK_NAME);
}
```

Run that in onResume, and just pop up a screen that says to connect to the right network if it returns false.  You may also want to register a broadcast receiver to listen for wifi connect/disconnect events and perform this check as needed there as well.

Comment: i have a doubt! what if in future the SSID is changed? then don't we have to give another update just for a small change.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager)getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
WifiInfo wifiInfo = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
wifiInfo.getSSID();
```

After getting the SSID, match it with your desired one. If the condition is met, then do whatever you want.

Comment: Mac address isn't what you want here, that identifies a router not a network

Comment: Use SSID.  That should identify the network.  So you were on the right track.

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own logic for that in launcher `Activity`.

```
WifiManager wifiMgr = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
WifiInfo wifiInfo = wifiMgr.getConnectionInfo();
String name = wifiInfo.getSSID();
```

above code is to get name of currently connected network name, you can make condition if it matches your predefined name, allow user to use your application.

Answer (score -1):

You could try something like this:

```
ConnectivityManager connManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
NetworkInfo mWifi = connManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);

if (!mWifi.isConnected()) {
// exit app here
}
```

make sure You have proper permission in Your AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"></uses-permission>
```

Related answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3841407/3693617