# Android Get Status of Wifi Connection

Tags: android, android-wifi, android-networking, android-connectivitymanager, android-connectionservice

I'm currently using `NetworkRequest` and `NetworkCallback` approach (recommended by Google official) to get status of Wifi connection, and it works partially.

I'm expecting the `onUnavailable()` will get called when: `close app -> turn off Wifi -> launch app`, however there is nothing happened:

```
private fun getNetworkRequest(): NetworkRequest {
    return NetworkRequest.Builder()
        .addTransportType(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI)    //restric to Wifi type only
        .build()
}

private fun getNetworkCallBack(): ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback {
    return object : ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback() {
        override fun onAvailable(network: Network) {            //works
            super.onAvailable(network)

            Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "Wifi is on!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }

        override fun onLost(network: Network) {                 //works
            super.onLost(network)

            Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "Wifi turns off!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }

        override fun onUnavailable() {                          //not works as expected
            super.onUnavailable()

            Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "Wifi unavailable!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    }
}

fun Fragment.getConnectivityManager() = requireContext().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as ConnectivityManager

override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()

    getConnectivityManager().registerNetworkCallback(networkRequest, networkCallback)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I got the solution:

```
val isWifiOn = with(getConnectivityManager()) {
    getNetworkCapabilities(activeNetwork)?.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI)
}
```

Demo: https://youtu.be/OHFrtXVW4x4