# How to check Wi-Fi switch state 'ON' or 'OFF' even if not connected to a WiFi network on Android

Tags: android, wifi

I need to develop a feature that is required checking Wi-Fi settings state 'ON' or 'OFF' even if not connected to a WiFi network on Android! I need to display a pop up!

```
 public static boolean CheckWifiConnection(Context context) {
    ConnectivityManager conMgr = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService (Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    return conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo() != null
            && conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo().isAvailable();
}
```

For an example: Think I am in a bus, I have turned on the WiFi. It is not connected to a wifi network, because there is no WiFi router near by. So How can my app knows wifi is on or off.

[image]

Comment: Do you want to specifically check for a "WiFi" connection or do you only care about the general network connectivity (Wifi or 4G/5G)?

Comment: @ADroid Only wifi. Not connection state, Want to know WiFi on or not, no need to worry it connected  to a wifi network

Comment: @ADroid Question was updated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this question I could use `WifiManager`.

```
public static boolean CheckWifiSwitch(Context context) {
    WifiManager wifiMgr = (WifiManager) context.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
    return wifiMgr.isWifiEnabled();
}
```

[WifiManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ConnectivityManager` to get network status

```
private boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
            ConnectivityManager connectivityManager
                    = (ConnectivityManager) activity.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
            return activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnected();
        }
```

Comment: Only for wifi switch on or off

Answer (score -1):

I think you should to use `ConnectivityManager`.

```
ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback networkCallback = new ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onAvailable(Network network) {
        // network available
    }

    @Override
    public void onLost(Network network) {
        // network unavailable
    }
};
```

[How to check a type of connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3841317/how-do-i-see-if-wi-fi-is-connected-on-android)

[ConnectivityManager](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=To9aHYD5OVk&t=228s&ab_channel=CodingWithMitch)

Comment: Not the network availability. Just want to know wifi is turned on or not. Phone's wifi state. It is not needed to connect to a wifi network.

Comment: Check the updated question!