# Check if user is connected via wifi or (Google Chrome on Android)

Tags: android, google-chrome

I'm writing a mobile website for Chrome mobile and would like to detect if the user is connected to the internet via wifi or 3g. Is that possible?

Comment: By web app do you mean an Android app that wraps a `WebView` or straight up a website that users need to access via Chrome? If the latter, I dont think Madison's response is what you are looking for...

Comment: Sorry, I should have clarified that. It's a mobile website, not a website wrapped in an app.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this thread: [ANDROID: if WiFi is enabled AND active, launch an intent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1811852/android-if-wifi-is-enabled-and-active-launch-an-intent) .  I think you might find what you are looking for.

Comment: I'm writing a mobile website. Sorry for the confusion, I clarified it in the first post.